# User access roles in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm working on the website using magento, and i currently work with a module for a real-state that client can upload there own products in admin panel. usually it could be done in magento admin panel. The problem is i need to give that user permission to add products and manage only there own products.

i ended up googling and i found a magento extension
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-permissions.html

What i want is to build my own like advanced permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For product Restriction based on User role. 
you can use **customer group** option of Magento.

you can also refer below link for more Information :

[Product Restriction Based on Customer Group](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-restriction-based-on-customer-group.html)

You can modified code based on your requirement.

Comment: Hi Ankur i will try this extension, its pretty near. Thanks.